# PYTHON /PANDAS VALUEERROR

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

hi there i am trying to make a trade bot with somedatas that i have collected from web. but i always get *Valueerror* my code is done for me i will try to plot it with ploty or something else but i need to pass this error first.if you can do it with a macd parameter i will be soo greatfull have a nice day.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot

from pyti.exponential_moving_average import exponential_moving_average as ema


class TradingModel:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.df = self.getData()

    def getData(self):


        base = 'https://api.binance.com'
        endpoint = '/api/v1/klines'
        params = '?&symbol=' + self.symbol + '&interval=1D'

        url = base + endpoint + params


        data = requests.get(url)
        dictionary = json.loads(data.text)


        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
        df = df.drop(range(6, 12), axis=1)


        col_names = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
        df.columns = col_names


        for col in col_names:
            df[col] = df[col].astype(float)


        df['fast_ema'] = ema(df['close'].tolist(), 12)
        df['slow_ema'] = ema(df['close'].tolist(), 26)
        df['macd_line']= df['fast_ema']-df['slow_ema']
        df['signal_line']= ema(df['macd_line'].tolist(),9)
        df['histogram']=df['macd_line']-df['signal_line']

        return df

    def strategy(self):


        df = self.df

        buy_signals = []

        for i in range(1, len(df['close'])):
            if (df['macd_line'][i]>df['signal_line'][i]) &  1>df['histogram'][i]>0 :
                buy_signals.append([df['time'][i], df['low'][i]])

        self.plotData(buy_signals=buy_signals)

    def plotData(self, buy_signals=False):
        df = self.df


        candle = go.Candlestick(
            x=df['time'],
            open=df['open'],
            close=df['close'],
            high=df['high'],
            low=df['low'],
            name="Candlesticks")


        fsma = go.Scatter(
            x=df['time'],
            y=df['macd_line'],
            name="Macd_line",
            line=dict(color=('rgba(102, 207, 255, 50)')))

        ssma = go.Scatter(
            x=df['time'],
            y=df['signal_line'],
            name="Signal_line ",
            line=dict(color=('rgba(255, 207, 102, 50)')))

        hsma = go.Scatter(
            x=df['time'],
            y=df['signal_line'],
            name="histogram ",
            line=dict(color=('rgba(255, 207, 102, 50)')))
        data = [candle, ssma, fsma,hsma]

        if buy_signals:
            buys = go.Scatter(
                x=[item[0] for item in buy_signals],
                y=[item[1] for item in buy_signals],
                name="Buy Signals",
                mode="markers",
            )

            sells = go.Scatter(
                x=[item[0] for item in buy_signals],
                y=[item[1] * 1.05 for item in buy_signals],
                name="Sell Signals",
                mode="markers",
            )

            data = [candle, ssma, fsma, hsma ,buys, sells]

        layout = go.Layout(title=self.symbol)
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

        plot(fig, filename=self.symbol)


def Main():
    symbol = "btcusdt"
    model = TradingModel(symbol)
    model.strategy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

I get this error

```
C:\Users\alper\PycharmProjects\tradingmodelpart1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/alper/PycharmProjects/tradingmodelpart1/tradingmodelpart1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alper/PycharmProjects/tradingmodelpart1/tradingmodelpart1.py", line 125, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:/Users/alper/PycharmProjects/tradingmodelpart1/tradingmodelpart1.py", line 120, in Main
    model = TradingModel(symbol)
  File "C:/Users/alper/PycharmProjects/tradingmodelpart1/tradingmodelpart1.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.df = self.getData()
  File "C:/Users/alper/PycharmProjects/tradingmodelpart1/tradingmodelpart1.py", line 30, in getData
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
  File "C:\Users\alper\PycharmProjects\tradingmodelpart1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1247, in from_dict
    return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\alper\PycharmProjects\tradingmodelpart1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 435, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\alper\PycharmProjects\tradingmodelpart1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 254, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\alper\PycharmProjects\tradingmodelpart1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 64, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Users\alper\PycharmProjects\tradingmodelpart1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 355, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message

Comment: As the error suggest, you are using scalar values hence you either change it to something else (use lists for example) or keep your scalar values and pass an index!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your code for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot

from pyti.exponential_moving_average import exponential_moving_average as ema


class TradingModel:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.df = self.getData()

    def getData(self):


        base = 'https://api.binance.com'
        endpoint = '/api/v1/klines'
        params = '?&symbol=' + self.symbol + '&interval=1d'

        url = base + endpoint + params
        print(url)

        data = requests.get(url)
        dictionary = json.loads(data.text)
        print(dictionary)


        df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
        print(df)
        df = df.drop(range(6, 12), axis=1)


        col_names = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
        df.columns = col_names


        for col in col_names:
            df[col] = df[col].astype(float)


        df['fast_ema'] = ema(df['close'].tolist(), 12)
        df['slow_ema'] = ema(df['close'].tolist(), 26)
        df['macd_line']= df['fast_ema']-df['slow_ema']
        df['signal_line']= ema(df['macd_line'].tolist(),9)
        df['histogram']=df['macd_line']-df['signal_line']

        return df

    def strategy(self):


        df = self.df

        buy_signals = []

        for i in range(1, len(df['close'])):
            if (df['macd_line'][i]>df['signal_line'][i]) &  1>df['histogram'][i]>0 :
                buy_signals.append([df['time'][i], df['low'][i]])

        self.plotData(buy_signals=buy_signals)

    def plotData(self, buy_signals=False):
        df = self.df


        candle = go.Candlestick(
            x=df['time'],
            open=df['open'],
            close=df['close'],
            high=df['high'],
            low=df['low'],
            name="Candlesticks")


        fsma = go.Scatter(
            x=df['time'],
            y=df['macd_line'],
            name="Macd_line",
            line=dict(color=('rgba(102, 207, 255, 50)')))

        ssma = go.Scatter(
            x=df['time'],
            y=df['signal_line'],
            name="Signal_line ",
            line=dict(color=('rgba(255, 207, 102, 50)')))

        hsma = go.Scatter(
            x=df['time'],
            y=df['signal_line'],
            name="histogram ",
            line=dict(color=('rgba(255, 207, 102, 50)')))
        data = [candle, ssma, fsma,hsma]

        if buy_signals:
            buys = go.Scatter(
                x=[item[0] for item in buy_signals],
                y=[item[1] for item in buy_signals],
                name="Buy Signals",
                mode="markers",
            )

            sells = go.Scatter(
                x=[item[0] for item in buy_signals],
                y=[item[1] * 1.05 for item in buy_signals],
                name="Sell Signals",
                mode="markers",
            )

            data = [candle, ssma, fsma, hsma ,buys, sells]

        layout = go.Layout(title=self.symbol)
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

        plot(fig, filename=self.symbol)


def Main():
    symbol = "BTCUSDT"
    model = TradingModel(symbol)
    model.strategy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help have a nice day it works

Comment: `1>df['histogram'][i]>0` at here i wanna make strategy for negative to positive turns. but when i do it gets error. i wanna mean that previous histogram will be negative and  f['histogram'][i] will be positive. how can i code this?

Answer (score 0):

I used `json_normalize` instead of `from_dict` and when I print the df this is what i get:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(dictionary)
print(df)

   code                                                msg
0 -1100  Illegal characters found in parameter 'symbol'...
```

Is that correct? If yes, `df = df.drop(range(6, 12), axis=1)` won't work because those columns don't exist.

Comment: i use it for getting data. it can be wrong

Comment: f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 6 elements
got this error